# Aligning div to top of body

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I currently have this design[image]

As you can see, the jumbotron (boostrap v5) is aligned in the center but I want it to be touching the very top of the body. I've tried playing around with margin, display, and align but I can't seem to work it out.

Here is the code so far:

```
body {display: flex; 
 align-items: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

.jumbotron {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  }
```

If I delete the body's align-items:center, the jumbotron aligns at the top but for some reason its height then increases to take up almost all the body. Why might that be? How can I keep the size of the jumbotron as it appears in the image attached but get it to align at the very top?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `align-items: center;` on body and add `align-self: flex-start;` to your jumbotron. Or just don't use display flex and if the jumbotron is the first item it will be at the top of the page.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.jumbotron {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}
```